# Inputs of different sizes bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, html

I have this problem - I need to make 3 INPUT, 1 wide (across the width of the screen) and below 2 small (exactly half the width of the first INPUT element), but it turns out that the size they are not the same. How to make an exact match width dimensions?

```
<form class="navbar-form">
<label>Where are you going?</label>
<input type="text" class="span8" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="5" placeholder="City, attraction, address, or airport">
<label>When?</label>
<input type="text" class="datepicker span4" id="dpd1" placeholder="Choose Arrive Date">
<input type="text" class="datepicker span4" id="dpd2" placeholder="Choose Depart Date">
</form>
```

[image]

you can see all code [here](http://tourlly.com/begin/)

Comment: This is a bootstrap problem, to get around this, you need to overwrite bootstraps size of span 4 or 8 span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this to avoid the extra space on inputs:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <input class="span12"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class='span6'>
            <input class="span12"/>
        </div>
        <div class='span6'>
            <input class="span12"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJDfw/1/)